# How do I determine if my addon is running in firefox or in fennec?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, fennec

I am making an addon for both firefox and fennec and I want to know if it is running on fennec or not.

Answer (score 1):

The [global Application object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Toolkit_API/extIApplication) (provided by [FUEL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/FUEL)) will give you various properties such as name or id that you can use to determine this.

Answer (score 1):

What sdwilsh said or [using nsIXULAppInfo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_nsIXULAppInfo).

If Fennec does support FUEL (I haven't checked), it's a matter of personal preference which one to use. FUEL is supposed to be a simpler-to-use wrapper around the nsI* components.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `document.getElementById("browsers")`. In firefox, it's null but in fennec it returns a HTMLDivElement object

Comment: It's null now, but that could easily change in the future.  It's better to use a more stable API.

Answer (score 0):

In the current version of the extensions API, the xul-app module exposes a name property which is set to either Firefox or Fennec. This seems to work nicely.

```
var xul_app = require('xul-app');
var isMobile = (xul_app.name.toLowerCase().indexOf('fennec') > -1);
```